# Encrypting in CryptoJS and decrypting in mCrypt not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, cryptojs

For the past 2 days I have been struggling with what I first thought would be a breeze to implemenent.

I am in need of a very simple and *non-secure* way to send a cipher thru AJAX and decrypt it server-side

**I am using AES from [CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#AES):**

**JS encryption**

```
    msg = "message";
    var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f');
    var iv  = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f');
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(msg, key, { iv: iv });

    var data_base64 = encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64); 
    var iv_base64   = encrypted.iv.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);       
    var key_base64  = encrypted.key.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);

    console.log(data_base64,iv_base64,key_base64) //If I use these keys in the PHP decryption it works

    return encrypted.toString();
```

---

...and **PHP decryption using [mCrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php)**

```
$encrypted = "f82126a59b76d86946a013d9f575d0d4"; //this is what the JS function above returned.
$key = "000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f"; //same key as in JS function
$iv = "101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f"; //same IV as in JS function

$plaintext = rtrim( mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $encrypted, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv ), "\t\0 " );

echo "Original string : " . $encrypted . "<br />\n"; 
echo "Decrypted string : " . $plaintext . "<br />\n";
```

Since I am using the same `IV`'s and `key`'s to encrypt I would expect that this would work decrypt just fine. However I seem to be missing something since I still see gibberish in the `plaintext.`

**EDIT:**

> Well it seems that the whole purpose of AES is that the `keys` and
>   `IV`'s I must use are output by CryptoJS (see the `console.log`'s in
>   the JS function). If I use those the function seems to run just fine.
>   But I don't want that actually since those keys are dynamically
>   generated thus each time I ran the JS function they change. *I just
>   need a shared private-key* between client and server that is used to
>   encrypt/decrypt and is static. As simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Your key is 128 bit (the length of $key is 32 hexadecimal characters, which means 16 byte or 128 bit). However, in your mcrypt_decrypt() call you're telling PHP to use `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` with a 256-bit key. Try using `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` instead. Normally ciphers should adapt to the length of the passed key, but it could be that PHP is padding the key with null bytes to use 256-bit encryption.

Secondly, in PHP mcrypt_decrypt is set to use the CBC mode (see `MCRYPT_MODE_CBC`). You don't specify which mode CryptoJS should use. Luckily for you, according to docs for CryptoJS, the CBC mode is the one used by default; however, since you're writing portable code you should consider making that explicit.

### edit

If it tells you that the key is too long, it's because you're not packing them. You're giving PHP an hex-encoded string long 32 bytes (256 bit), which is not your key! To get the binary data you need to do:

```
$key = pack('H*', "000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f");
$iv = pack('H*', "101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f");
```

the `pack('H*', $str);` function converts an hex representation to the binary string.

Comment: err I'm not sure: When I use 128bit mode in mCrypt I get this:  `Warning: mcrypt_decrypt(): The IV parameter must be as long as the blocksize in C:\wamp\www\index2.php on line 10`. I think the keys I am using in PHP are supposed to be the CryptoJS output keys and not the static ones. However I'd like to encrypt and decrypt with a static key that I just share between client/server. I'm editing my question now.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides I've updated my answer. Let me know if that fixes your problem now. (still with the 128-bit mode)

Comment: no, I think the whole point is that the key/IV i am using are just initializing the encryption. The key and IV needed to decrypt are generated on-the-fly with the cipher. Your updated code though no longer generates an error about the block size, but the `plaintext` is giberrish nonetheless. See my edited question

Comment: Can you try calling the CBC mode directly on CryptoJS? Apparently the AES class is an higher-level one that derives another key.

Comment: Or, even better, use SJCL: https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl (use sjcl.cipher and not the high-level sjcl.encrypt )

Answer (score 0):

`MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` is not the same as AES. The `256` relates to the *block size* of the cipher, not the key size.

Quick history lesson - AES was a competition that was eventually won by an algorithm called Rijndael. Rinjdael is a cipher defined for several block sizes (128, 160, 192, 224 and 256 bits). However, for AES only the 128-bit block size was selected.

The block size defines the size of the IV, when you use a mode that needs an IV (like CBC-mode). So for AES, you'll always need a 128-bit IV, regardless of key size. The supported key sizes are 128, 192 or 256 bits.

In PHP, one can use AES by using the cipher `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128`.